# Rewrite medfilt1 MATLAB function to support codegen

Tags: matlab

I am writing a MATLAB script that uses the medfilt1 function. Here is an example using an order of 100:

```
  median_filter_results = medfilt1(my_data, 100);
```

When trying to export the MATLAB code via codegen, an error message states that medfilt1 is not supported. Looking on the [MATLAB documentation website](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-and-objects-supported-for-cc-code-generation.html), I can tell that it is not there, while medfilt2 is. This makes me think that the function is probably rather easy to reproduce.

When reading [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/260011-how-can-i-write-the-same-code-without-using-medfilt1-command), the authors make this comment:

> You can use the median() function. Then you just have to put that inside a for loop, which is extremely trivial.

However, I am not entirely sure I know what that means since the [median](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) function returns back one number vs a vector of the medfilt1 function. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Median_filter) goes a bit further, where they show a sliding window, through which one could use the median function. However, I am not entirelly too certain that this is what MATLAB is doing.

How can I rewrite the medfilt1 function (vector of data and order of 100) in a codegen safe way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation using sliding window of `median` in a for loop:

Implementing a sliding window is simple.
There is a small complication regarding the margins.
The implementation pads the margins with zeros (default padding of `medfilt1`).

Here is the implementation and a test:

```
n = 100;

%Test using an array of random elements.
A = rand(1, 1000);

B = my_medfilt1(A, n);

%Reference for testing
refB = medfilt1(A, n);

%Display 1 if result of my_medfilt1 is the same as medfilt1
is_equal = all(B == refB)


function y = my_medfilt1(x, n)
%Perform one dimensional median filter in a loop.
%Assume x is one dimensional row vector.
if size(x, 1) > 1
    error('x must be a row vector')
end

y = zeros(1, length(x)); %Initialize space for storing resut

%Add n/2 zeros from each side of x (this is the default padding of medfilt1.
x = padarray(x, [0, floor(n/2)], 0, 'both');

%Sliding window
for i = 1:length(y)
    y(i) = median(x(i:i+n-1));
end

end
```

Comment: Ah, this is a clear explanation. Makes understanding orders and med filter function easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the 2d filter is supported, you could repurpose it.

```
x=rand(100,1);
y1=medfilt1(x,11);
y2=medfilt2(x,[11,1]);
all(y1==y2)
```

Otherwise, read up what a median filter does. It replaces the element with the median of it and it's surrounding neighbors. Size of the neighborhood is your parameter n.